# Adding more variables to an array of objects in java

Tags: java, arrays, oop, attributes, instance

I've made a bit of a mess on a project of mine. I have to create an array of objects. I have made an array but it only has 1 field 'myMonths' referring to the length of time of the project.
In my main method:

```
case 1:

    int n = 1;    //int n = number of projects
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    //myMonths = new int[amount];

    System.out.println("** Only projects with a duration between 2 and 12 months can be included **");
    System.out.println("What was the duration of your projects in months?");

    for(int i=0; i<1; i++){
        int a = sc.nextInt();

        //display error message
        if((a < 2) || (a > 12)){
            System.out.println(" Please enter an amount between 2 and 12 months. ");
        }

        //add to the array
        else{
            myMonths[index++] = a;
        }
    }

    calc.setMyMonths(myMonths); //creating the object
    break;
```

In my class on separate file:

```
public class MenuTestClass{

private int myMonths[];
private double average; //store average value of numbers
private boolean averageCanBeCalculated;
private int max; // store max number from array. to be calculated

public MenuTestClass(){
    myMonths = new int[5];
    }

 public MenuTestClass(int[] myMonths){
   this.myMonths = myMonths;
   }
 public void setMyMonths(int[] values){ //declare setter method
   myMonths = values;
   }
```

I should have added in two more fields, both strings. Is there a way I can add more fields/attributes to this array and have them viewable at the same time under 1 index? For example at [0] projectName, projectManager, myMonths ie(string, string, integer).
Any advice would be great, I am getting really confused with OOP. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Thanks for editing the code! :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, create a class containing your three properties:

```
class MyContainer {
    
    public MyContainer(int durationMonths, String projectName, String projectManager) {
        this.durationMonths = durationMonths;
        this.projectName = projectName;
        this.projetManager = projectManager;
    }

    public int durationMonths;
    public String projectName;
    public String projectManager;
}
```

Then create an array of this class with:

```
MyContainer[] myArray = new MyContainer[numberOfProjects];
```

Add items to the array like this:

```
myArray[0] = new MyContainer(3, "super project", "awesome manager");
```

Comment: Syntax error. It should be: `MyContainer[] myContainers = new MyContainer[];`

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer!  Sorry I'm really confused with this stuff. Do I need to get rid of my array called myMonths[ ]?

Comment: Updated the example code, I'm writing this on mobile so I messed up with the array name as Hovercraft pointed out. Aleo111 you should replace it with the array of the objects that will hold your values.

Comment: I'm just wondering if I'm declaring my array too many times. I've declared it in my main method as well as in my class file, am I doing this incorrectly?                                       int myMonths[] = new int[amountOfProjects];
        int index = 0;
     int num;

        while(choice !=6){ //while option 6 is not chosen keep showing the menu

            switch (choice){

Comment: in the message above you can see how I've declared it in my main method, just before I go into switch statements